# Unable to upload images. Ghost CMS in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, docker-volume, ghost-blog

When upload any images (post, logo and etc.), printing the error "Request was rejected due to server error".
Container reloaded per try to upload, without any errors in "docker logs".
I am tried different params for chmod and chown, anything don't help me.

My docker-compose file:

```
blog_ghost:
  image: ghost
  ports:
    - 8989:2368
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
  environment:
    url: https://exaple.site
    database__client: mysql
    database__connection__host: mariadb
    database__connection__user: DB_NAME
    database__connection__password: secure_password
    database__connection__database: USER
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - /storage/blog_ghost:/var/lib/ghost/content/
```

In error.log nothing, empty file.

[image: screenshot error]

[image: Permission in the container]

In .log this messages:
[image: docker logs]

I tried to build the container on the 4.3.3 version of the image. It works fine and the images are uploaded.

Comment: Can you try ghost run form terminal?

Comment: @RichardRublev I can't do that. Since ghost is running in a container and it is running, when running "ghost run" a message is displayed that "Port 2368 is already in use by another program. Is another Ghost instance already running? "

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @RichardRublev Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Can you open the browser console and add to your question the actual API error you're getting from the network tab? Maybe that can shed some light on what's happening.

Comment: having the exact same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

After ran

root:/var/lib/ghost/versions/5.33.8/node_modules# `rm -R sharp`

in the container console, I can finally upload images without crashing the web server.

"sharp is a high-performance image processing module for Node.js. This module assists with UGC management by offering an easy solution for reading, enhancing, and saving image files. sharp compresses images faster than most other Node.js modules, like ImageMagick, Jimp, or Squoosh, and produces high-quality results."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).